# How to find the p-norm that meets the requirements?

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra

On page 183 of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000006641172&d=CB6E1ED34FB8B2B0879DD74D4A4AA569&fenlei=130116) there is **Theorem 3**:

[image]

In other words, if the spectral radius of a matrix `B` is less than 1, there must be a norm $ ||B||_{p}$, so that $||B||_{p}<1$.

```
N[Eigenvalues[MatrixForm[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 1/5, 2/5}}]]]
```

But the following norms are all greater than 1:

```
N[Norm[MatrixForm[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 1/5, 2/5}}], 1]]
N[Norm[MatrixForm[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 1/5, 2/5}}], 2]]
N[Norm[MatrixForm[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 1/5, 2/5}}], Infinity]]
```

What can I do to find the p-norm that makes $||A||_{p}<1$ hold?

**Related exercises(2001武汉 岩石 数值分析):**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The spectral radius of your matrix is *not* less than 1:

```
Norm[N[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 1/5, 2/5}}]]
   1.34485

Max[SingularValueList[N[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 1/5, 2/5}}]]]
   1.34485
```

Comment: In textbooks, the spectral radius of a matrix is the maximum value of the absolute value of the eigenvalue of this matrix.

Comment: I feel you may have misunderstood a theorem somewhere. The theorem I recall is that any induced norm is greater than or equal to the largest absolute value of the matrix's eigenvalues. Can you check again?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am mainly confused about theorem 3 in the textbook, which is a conclusion in this book.